# Is ToString() optimized by compiler?

Tags: .net, tostring, compiler-optimization

Suppose I've following Code:

```
Console.WriteLine("Value1: " + SomeEnum.Value1.ToString() + "\r\nValue2: " + 
                    SomeOtherEnum.Value2.ToString());
```

Will Compiler Optimize this to:

```
Console.WriteLine("Value1: " + SomeEnum.Value1 + "\r\nValue2: " +
                         SomeOtherEnum.Value2);
```

I've checked it with IL Disassembler and there are calls to 
`IL_005a:  callvirt   instance string [mscorlib]System.Object::ToString()`

I don't know if JIT optimizes this.

Comment: It's late and I may be missing something, but how is this an optimization?

Comment: @Jon Seigel I shun to write `ToString()` where ever I can avoid it just to type less, but a friend said that it is unnecessary overhead so I asked here to remove any doubts.

Comment: When `Value1` is of type string, the JIT compiler can optimize calls to `ToString` away.

Comment: So foolish  of me to ask this. Yes you are right @Steven I actually wanted to know about `ToString()` being called on strings. Oh what a bloat on my knowledge baa baaa LOL

Comment: The real optimization happens at runtime, as there is a high chance of such calls getting inlined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, it's the other way around. This:

```
Console.WriteLine("Value1: " + SomeEnum.Value1 + "\r\nValue2: " +
                     SomeOtherEnum.Value2);
```

Is translated by the compiler into (the equivalent of) this:

```
string s = String.Concat("Value1: ", SomeEnum.Value1.ToString(), "\r\n Value2: ", SomeOtherEnum.Value2.ToString());
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

In both case, the same IL is generated. If you're asking whether the JIT turns that into:

```
string s = String.Concat("Value1: ", "Value1", "\r\n Value2: ", "Value2");
Console.WriteLine(s);
```

Then the answer is no. Though I wonder why that would be a problem for you?

Comment: see my comment on @Jon Seigel's comment

Comment: OK, well anyway, the two lines you posted are basically equivalent. If you have a tool like ReSharper, it actually notifies you when calls to ToString() are redundant. It's not that there's any performance hit, it's just not needed.